# Как в базе данных лучше хранить инфу о товаре?

Tags: php, mysql

Складской учёт.
Есть товары с кодом, наименованием, количеством, ценой.
Товары при закупке имеют разную цену!
Как лучше организовать хранение таких данных в БД?
Наверняка многие с таким сталкивались? интересует сам алгоритм дальнейшей работы с такими товарами.

пример: приходная накладная

```
2096 | СЫР РОССИЙСКИЙ | 216 кг. |  **78** руб. |
2096 | СЫР РОССИЙСКИЙ | 60 кг.  |  76 руб.     |
```

В примере код, наименование совпадает. **В БД уже есть товар с кодом 2096, наименованием СЫР РОССИЙСКИЙ, остаток 16 кг. А ВОТ ЦЕНА 73 руб.**
Я же не могу заменить тупо цену на новую, тогда весь отчет уже будет не правильным.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2 таблицы

таблица товаров:
id товара | наименование

таблица накладная:
id товара | вес | сумма